# I can't scan QR Code in iPhone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Below code already working in iPhone 5c,5s and iPhone 6 with IOS 7 and IOS 8, but not work in iPhone 4,

```
AVCaptureMetadataOutput *captureMetadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];

[_captureSession addOutput:captureMetadataOutput];

dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue;
dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
[captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue];
[captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray  arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];

_videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];

[_videoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
[_videoPreviewLayer setFrame:_viewPreview.bounds];
[_viewPreview.layer addSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer];
// Start video capture.
[_captureSession startRunning];
```

didOutputMetadataObjects  method not call in iPhone 4

Comment: What's the size of your QRCode ? Is it "big enough"? Since the camera has been improved, I faced this issue with small QRCode that my iPhone 4S couldn't read, but the iPhone 5S could. We had to set the minimum size of our QRCode to the smallest one that the iPhone 4S could detect.

Comment: frame of QRCode is = (5 20; 310 401);